# Batch how get Batch CMD to popup on the second Monitor, not the Default Monitor

Tags: batch-file

Batch how get Batch CMD to popup on the second Monitor, not the Default Monitor as always hidden behind Games and when ALT+TAB it [to Move CMD to second] BUT it always back to Games as hard time to move the Batch CMD popup to Second Monitoretc

Then Batch I use is:

```
REM Store systems current time into BEFOREDATE var as mm-dd-yy
SET TODAY=%date:~0,2%-%date:~3,2%-%date:~6,8%

Start "" "Game Dir\ etc.exe"
Pause

REM Set the below date to date you wish to roll your system date back to
DATE 10-12-20
Pause

REM Set system date back to current date
DATE %TODAY%
```

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16126938/421195.  FYI, I'd strongly encourage you to consider using Powershell for your scripts, vs. .bat files.

Comment: Sorry i a noob confused, I copy from <# : batch portion etc to finally { exit 0 } save so when i double it it did popup then disappear

Comment: That script takes arguments - first, which monitor you're putting the program on (1 or 2) and second, the program you're running.

Comment: Help me do the Batch script for CMD to open on second monitor ?